# Send multiple commands with Plink and SSH

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssh, plink

I'm using a batch file which contains the following information:

```
plink.exe -ssh loginuser@192.168.0.1 -pw intec -m t.txt
```

`m.txt` contains user and password example:

```
su
intec
```

Result:

```
 C:\Plink>plink.exe -ssh loginuser@192.168.0.1 -pw intec -m t.txt
 Password:_
```

The problem is that the cursor is waiting for the password.
How do I send the password to pass this step?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. just a guess, have you tried to add a new line in the txt?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the password, I believe it needs to use the -pw option followed by the actual password, not a filename.